# Grails Jquery-UI datepicker

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

In grails by using the jquery UI plugin how do I set a domain attribute (Date weekEndDate) to the date selected by the user with the datepicker feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this .

```
 <!doctypte html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    <title><g:message code="User's profile" /></title>
    <g:javascript library="jquery" />
    <r:require module="jquery-ui"/>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() 
    { ("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'}); 
    }) 
    </script>        
    </head>
      <body>
      <div >
      <g:form controller="xyz" action ="abc">
      date :  <input type="text" name="weekEndDate" id="weekEndDate" />
      <g:submitButton name="click" />
      </g:form>
      </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Ref Link :- http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: You will also have to parse the string to date in controller by doing something like this: yourDomain.weekEndDate = new Date().parse('yy/MM/dd',params.weekEndDate)